# How to implement addTarget:atSelector:forControlEvent: on the sending object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating custom control that behave slightly like a `UISlider`. I would like to allow objects using this class to be able to `addTarget:atSelector:forControlEvent:` the event would be here `UIControlEventValueChanged`.

How can I make my custom `UISlider` like `object send the selector` on the target upon value changed ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just make your object a subclass of `UIControl` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

here is the tutorial link which is having sample code as well at the end.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control

hope this will help you.